# Can't add (Growl) Framework to Release version of my App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, frameworks, growl

I've created a new App and want to test it in a release version. So I copied the Growl Framework to my project folder and added into XCode.

Then I copied the new files in the target in my project and copied the `Growl.framework` to the new "Copy Files" Framework folder in "Targets". When I debug my project, it's all right, but if I change the version to "Release" and then Build, there is the Red "1" on my XCode icon in the Dock. I dont know why this error comes; I've searched in Google but I can't find anything.

Can anyone Help me please?! Here is the Picture of my Copied Files:

[XCode http://b1.s3.quickshareit.com/bild15ead2.png](http://b1.s3.quickshareit.com/bild15ead2.png)

Answer (score 3):

Try ordering the Copy Files phase above the link phase.

> When i debug my Project, its all right, but if i change the Version to "Release" and than Build -> there is the Red "1" on my XCode icon in the Dock,

Well, what does the error say?

Comment: The error is not visible, in the Debugger, there is no error just the 1 on my Icon

Comment: The error is a build error, not a run error. Thus, you need to look in the Build Log, not the Debugger.

Comment: Sorry, forgot it:

pbxcp: warning: couldn't strip: /Users/ahmet/Desktop/Release/TaskApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/Growl.framework/Versions/A/Growl: No such file or directory

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. Even so, like I said, move the Copy Files phase above the Link Binary with Libraries phase.

Comment: and: Error (X) Command: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp failed with exit code 1

Comment: “malformed object”? That's interesting. What version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 3):

[alt text http://b2.s3.quickshareit.com/bild23a027.png](http://b2.s3.quickshareit.com/bild23a027.png)

"malformed object: Unknown load command 5"

This usually indicates that you have a binary that was built on a later version of Mac OS X (e.g. SnowLeopard) and you're trying to link it on an earlier version of Mac OS X (e.g. 10.5 Leopard).

Ensure you have a correct version of the Growl framework for your development environment and OS.

Comment: Reading your answer reminded me that there were, indeed, problems using version 1.2 of the Growl framework on Leopard, because we had its deployment target set to 10.6 for x86_64 (oops). We fixed it and released a 1.2.1 version last month: http://code.google.com/p/growl/downloads/detail?name=Growl-1.2.1-Framework.tbz @ahmet2106: use that.

Comment: @Peter Hosey This does not realy change something. But I think you both are right, it must be something with my Version: XCode 3.1.4 and Mac 10.5.6 For this I will buy me Snow Leopard -.- I've no other chance becaute the Framework 1.2.1 doesn't change anything in my Project, dont know why...